# A function in $L^2([0,1])$ but not in $L^n([0,1] )$ for $n>2$

Tags: measure-theory

Please indicate an example of a function in $L^2([0,1])$ but not in $L^n([0,1] )$ for any $n>2$?. The known examples are for $ n < 1 $ only.

Comment: Ingredients: a power of $x$ and logarithm. Combine them so that $\int_0^1 f^2$ is just barely convergent.

Comment: I know an example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Bare handed approach: Let $I_n=[1/2^{n+1},1/2^n], n = 0,1,\dots $ Define $f= 2^{n/2}/n$ on $I_n.$ Then $\int_0^1f^2 =  \sum 1/(2n^2) < \infty.$ If $p>2,$ then $\int_0^1 f^p = \sum 2^{(p/2-1)n}/2n^p =\infty.$

Comment: Thanks @zhw! Nice example.